# how to choose the range in histc? Why is there a 0 as indices?

Tags: matlab

i have a question regarding histc:
I choose the max and min of a sorted signal as my range.

```
      ma = ssigPE(end);
      mi = ssigPE(1);
      range = mi:ma;
      [bincountsO,indO2] = histc(ssigPE, range);
```

so the range i get back is:
         range = [-1.097184703736132 -0.097184703736132 0.902815296263868]

my problem is that just 2 bins get develop, so bincountsO has 2 bins
and indO2 has values as 0, 1 and 2

What am I doing wrong? I guess I m using the range wrong. I read the text here:

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html#inputarg_binranges

but I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bin ranges tell you where do bins start and stop. So a value of `[0 1 2 7]`for example, will give 3 bins: `[0 1]` , `[1 2]` , `[2 7]`

In matlab if you do `mi:ma` it will create an array from the value `mi` to `ma` with a step of 1. With your values, that gives just 3 values, hence 2 bins. There are 2 ways of creating a given step size length vectors.

Step size if 100 as an example

```
range=mi:(ma-mi)/100:ma;
```

alternatively, and way clearer

```
range=linspace(mi,ma,100)
```

Comment: thank you. Linspace is nice there. I know that it should give me 2 bins. But still I don't know why it gives me as indO2 3 values. 0 , 1 and 2.
Do you have an explanation for that?

Comment: @ele indx tells you in which bin do the values of `ssigPE` fall. If the values are outside range, then the result is 0. This is an histogram, therefore the amount of data in `ssigPE` is not related to the amount of bins. indx is `size(ssifPE)`

Comment: thank you. Now i know for sure that 0 is the default value. Wasn't mentioned in the description.

Comment: @AnderBiguri - Hola!  I've created a MATLAB chat room for us to discuss things MATLAB related, or for discussions that span beyond the limitations of a single comment.  Visit us when you have time! - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab